# how to modified wordpress category url like www.example.com/m/a1 to www.example.com/category/m/a1

Tags: wordpress, url

i have wordpress site .I config category urls to not contain world "category"  but some later i change it .
now in google i have both `www.example.com/m/a1`  and  `www.example.com/category/m/a1`

and so i get not found error for `www.example.com/m/a1`  because it changed to `www.example.com/category/m/a1`

Is any way to redirect All Url Format like `www.example.com/m/a1` to `www.example.com/category/m/a1` without loss none of 2 urls?

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect all those pages by defining `htaccess` rule like this:

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^m/(.*)$ /category/m/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

This will redirect all `www.example.com/m/anypage` to `www.example.com/category/m/anypage`

PS: Please be careful while using these rules, small mistake can crash the site.

Hope it helps! :)